# React form using Express API returns Cannot POST /

Tags: reactjs, express

I was able to get a form working when using pug as the view engine with Express.js. But when I tried to use React, I have not been able to get form handling to work properly.

```
// Component.js
  </React.Fragment>
         // API_POST_URL=http://localhost:4000/api/donate
      <form action={process.env.API_POST_URL} method='post' id='testForm'> 
        <input type="hidden" name='step' value='3' />
        <button type='submit'>Post Test form</button>
      </form>
  </React.Fragment>
```

.

```
// index.js in another project folder
router.post('/api/donate', (req, res, next) => {

 // code testing for earlier steps removed

 else if (req.body.step === '3') {
      res.json({ message : "here's a response back"});
  }
});
```

The front end runs on port 3000, the back end on port 4000. Connecting the projects together incorrectly may be the issue. Routing is another possibility.

I have been able to receive a response object using Postman requests to the ENV variable URL above (http://localhost:4000/api/donate)

Answer (score 1):

You code will make page refresh and you will loose the state of application which is not the goal of SPA's.

You can do this way:

```
</React.Fragment>
  <form onSubmit={submitFormHandler()}> 
    <input type="hidden" name='step' value='3' />
    <button type='submit'>Post Test form</button>
  </form>
```

Store above field in component state and pass it to submitFormHandler()

Use axios to submit form using http.

```
submitFormHandler = (data) => { axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/donate',data);}
```